# Alfresco integration with Liferay

Tags: content-management-system, liferay, alfresco, liferay-6, enterprise-portal

I'm wondering if Alfresco Out Of the Box can be configured to integrate with Liferay.

Or, must it be extended using custom content types/models before I can integrate it with Liferay.

Have you tried either of these? How has your experience been? We are using community Alfresco and Enterprise Liferay. I'm trying to see my options here. May be my question is too vague. Please throw in ideas if you think there's some aspects I'm completely missing.

Comment: What are the requirements of your integration? If you don't know what you're trying to achieve then I would recommend that you do some further home work by playing around with them both.

Comment: I do agree with Will;  you should know if you want to add just a portlet with maybe some Document Browser or if you'd like to call webscripts from your own parts of application...